# Make dashboard box title bold using CSS

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am using R Shiny dashboard for a R shiny app. I have included css file to style the app. I need to change box title to bold. Below is minimal example of `ui.R`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

body <-
  dashboardBody(tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "my_style.css")
  ),
  tabItems(tabItem(tabName = "test",
                   fluidRow(
                     box(
                       collapsible = TRUE,
                       width = 3,
                       status = "primary",
                       solidHeader = T,
                       title = "Test"
                     )
                   ))))

dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(), dashboardSidebar(), body)
```

And below is `my_style.css` file

```
.box.box-solid.box-primary>.box-header{
  background: rgb(0, 129, 201);
  color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 18px;
  font-weight; bold;
}

.box.box-solid.box-primary{
  font-family: OpenSans;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000000;
}
```

The problem is in .box-header portion. The box changes background color and text color; but not font-size and font-weight.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about:

```
.box-header h3 {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Great idea! I've found typo

    `fonts-weight: bold;`

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking to increase the font size, you will need an additional parameter (or at least I did):

```
.box-header h3.box-title {
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 24px;
}
```